# using multiple search boxes to filter 2 tables: can this be done and how?

Tags: excel, vba, search, filter

I have two tables (ErrorSummary and VolumeSummary) that describe some variables for my entire team. The tables have the same number of rows, as each row header is the name of one employee. There are also some affiliated charts that are connected to the data.

I want to create 4 search fields at the top of the sheet so that the user can compare the data for 4 employees at once.

I tried to code this, but this is the line that is getting tripped up:

```
'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
 Set DataRange = sht.Range("A41:O72") 'Cell Range

'Retrieve User's Search Input
 mySearch = sht.Shapes    ("staff1""staff2""staff3""staff4").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
```

^ the user search input line. I'm trying to get it to reference all the shapes one by one. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want `mySearch` to be a string with the text from all four shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
 Set DataRange = sht.Range("A41:O72") 'Cell Range

'Retrieve User's Search Input
 mySearch = sht.Shapes("staff1").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
 mySearch = mySearch & " " & sht.Shapes("staff2").TextFrame.Characters.Text
 mySearch = mySearch & " " & sht.Shapes("staff3").TextFrame.Characters.Text
 mySearch = mySearch & " " & sht.Shapes("staff4").TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

That will make `mysearch` a string with the text from all four shapes with a space between each.